# Display README for GitHub repository based on Operating System

Tags: github, operating-system, readme

**Background:**

When you land on a `GitHub` repository page on the website, it automatically renders the `README.md` file that lives on the root.

---

**Question:**

I want to have a separate one for `iOS` and `Windows`, and display the appropriate one based on the operating system the page is viewed on/from. Is this something you could do?

---

My current in-mind solution is to just have a super large file with clickable tags for the `iOS` and `Windows` sections, so that a user can click and jump to that section - this is not ideal though, as this file would grow extremely large (it is used as a setup guide).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to show a different README based on the viewer's OS, and I believe that's a good thing. I've frequently had to look something up on one device and use it on another.

What's to say a user wouldn't need to look up the Windows instructions from their iPhone?

> My current in-mind solution is to just have a super large file with clickable tags for the `iOS` and `Windows` sections, so that a user can click and jump to that section - this is not ideal though, as this file would grow extremely large (it is used as a setup guide).

This sounds like a good solution to me, though you're right that it could get unwieldy if you've got a lot of content.

Why not use [GitHub's wiki feature](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-wikis/) for detailed documentation? Windows and iOS could each have their own page, or pages. Your README can still contain some basic information and link to the wiki.

Alternatively, you could publish a website using [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) using content from [a dedicated `gh-pages` branch or a `docs/` directory in your `master` branch](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).